# Append and replacing data in r

Tags: r, data

I am writing a few lines of codes to create a data table full of NAs but don't know how to append the data of results into the data table I created while replacing the position of NAs.
Here is my data table
    [image]

```
games<-10
game_results<-as.data.frame(matrix(NA,games,3))
install.packages("data.table")
library(data.table)
setnames(game_results,c("V1","V2","V3"),c("winner","round","winnerscore"))
game_results
```

Answer (score 0):

You could change in this case with command

```
game_results$winner[1] <- "Dad"
```

But this copies the whole table, so i will recomend you to create an empty data in another way

```
game_results <- setNames(data.table(matrix(nrow = 10, ncol = 3)), c("winner","round","winnerscore"))
```

and assignment by reference in the way you prefer (hole column or specific cell), [here](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/data.table/versions/1.12.0/topics/%3A%3D) instructions for both cases.